# Rounding in R with print statement

Tags: r, printing, rounding-error

```
Q4 <-flights %>%
  filter(origin=="JFK") %>% 
  group_by(month,day) %>% 
  summarise(mean=round(mean(distance),digits=2)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mean)) %>% 
  head(5)
print(Q4)
```

With the above code, the Q4 object is
[image]

However, when I try use the print statement print(Q4) I am getting the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUkLo.jpg)

I thought I handled the rounding issues with my summarise line, but this is not outputting to the print statement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUkLo.jpg)

Comment: Hi Bob, thats a display issue/feature. Its addressed here: https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/numbers.html - so you need to format is `Q4 |> mutate(mean = pillar::num(mean, digits = 2))`

Comment: |> is causing an error in my code. I am using tidyverse

Comment: replace it with `%>%` AND you should update your R version ;)